# Inexplicable cross-browser differences

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have 2 cross-browser issues on [my page](http://www.mud-kings.com/events/) (http://www.mud-kings.com/events/) for which I can't find any explanation:

1) Under the four big square yellow icons at the bottom of the page, you can read "INDIVIDUAL", "GROUP", "CHILD" and "FAMILY" on Firefox and IE, but they are invisible on Chrome (the A links are gray in Chrome Firebug for no apparent reason)

2) Also clicking on the splash icon "register" on top of the footer displays a lightbox with a close cross icon top right. On FF and IE the style of this link (id = 'exit') works, but on Chrome they simply aren't applied, again for no apparent reason.

Comment: looks good for me.... what version of chrome are you running?

Comment: No problems here // Chrome 26 and 27 Canary

Comment: +1, fine for me here. you gots a wacky Chrome goin on.

Comment: Works here too... Clear your cache... Refresh three times... turn it on again off again.

Comment: Restarted Chrome, works now. Thx all. Lost 45 minutes in the process gmnmGnmg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem before and it turned out to be a cache issue, try restarting Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use vendor prefixes to fix the individual problem for each browser.

-webkit-transition: 
-moz-transition: 
-ms-transition: 
-o-transition: 
transition: